# genral error in sqlexception using jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

What is the problem in this code?

It always shows sqlexception general error, or it goes into debug process.

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class FunctionDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Data","Kanan","kanu");
            CallableStatement cs = c.prepareCall("? = call func(?)");
            cs.setInt(1, 5);
            cs.execute();
            System.out.println(cs.getInt(1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the JDBC-ODBC bridge was removed some time ago - what version of Java are you using? And exactly what does your `Exception` say? Oh, and `cs.setInt(2, 5);`

Comment: If you use SQL Server, you should use the mssql-jdbc driver, not ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems, **first** you miss the `{}`, **second** you should to specify what is the Out Parameter is, I will consider it an INTEGER so your program should look like this :

```
String query = "{ ? = call func(?)}"; 
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(sql);  

//set the return parameter
cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);

//your function take an int in the second position not in the 1st
cs.setInt(2, 5);
cs.execute();

System.out.println(cs.getInt(1));
```

Hope this can help you.